# Rails 4 activeadmin 1.0.0pre uninitialized constant on application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am getting an uninitialized constant after bundle installing the activeadmin gem from master. I can run my app just fine on a different branch without activeadmin.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

Stacktrace:

`` /Users/nhamidjaja/dev/rails/bourbon/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Bourbon>': uninitialized constant Bourbon::Rails::Application (NameError)
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/dev/rails/bourbon/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bourbon/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bourbon/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bourbon/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bourbon/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/nhamidjaja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@bourbon/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, activeadmin has a dependency on the bourbon gem and happens to be the same name as my app. Oops.